# Angular2 template with open elements

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to build a div structure out of the below json. 
I'm having difficulties doing this because I can't figure out
how to crate open div-tags.

`<div *ngIf="a = b">` does not work becuase I need to close it.

I cant put it in a `ng-container` because then I get an exception

```
<ng-container *ngIf="el.tagState == 'OPEN'">
   <div >&lt;{{el.name}}&gt;</div>
   <div class="block">
</ng-container>
```

`Error: Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "ng-container" ...`

Json

```
[
{ "name": "names", "tagState": "OPEN" },
{ "name": "name", "tagState": "COMPLETE", "data": "John" },
{ "name": "name", "tagState": "COMPLETE", "data": "Doe" },
{ "name": "names", "tagState": "CLOSE" }
]
```

Desired template output

```
<div class="root-block">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="row">&lt;names&gt;</div>
            <div class="block">
                <div class="row"><span>&lt;name&gt;</span><span class="data">John</span><span>&lt;name&gt;</span></div>
                <div class="row"><span>&lt;name&gt;</span><span class="data">Doe</span><span>&lt;name&gt;</span></div>
            </div>
        <div class="row">&lt;names&gt;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need open div tags?

Comment: The block div need to be open until I get an entry with tagState=close otherwise I get <div class="block"></div>

Comment: Angular components can't have invalid HTML in the templates.

Comment: Also `<ng-container></ng-container>` can't have content. What is that supposed to do?

Comment: I think the best way is to prepare the data structure in code the way you want or need it and then use `*ngFor` to create the DOM intead of putting too much logic into the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the data structure to be hierarchical and then I created a recursive component to render the data structure.